# Android Material transitions, Fragments and AppCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, transition, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use AppCompat library to have all the Lollipop shared transitions possible. Basically, in an activity, there is fragment A, with a recyclerview in it with some textview in each row. When I click on an item of this recyclerview, I'd like to launch fragment B sharing this textview to the fragment B.

I managed to make it work if it's between two activities but is it possible to achieve shared transitions between two fragments ? And if so, a quick hint/snippet/sample (depending on your awesomeness) would be very appreciated as I'm trying hard without success so far!

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember to use the support version for the `Activity`, `Fragment`, `FragmentManager`, any `Transition` and `PathMotion`.

Second, I am supposing that in the layout file of the main activity there is a FrameLayout with ID `container` and your shared TextView has ID `mySharedTextView`.

In Kotlin:

Your MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
        FirstFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
    }

    // The listener implementation from the first fragment
    override fun onItemSelected(id: Long, view: View) {

        // The second fragment
        val secondFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance(itemId)

        // Shared elements transition (always on the second fragment). These transitions are examples and for the TextView you will probably want some others. You can also inflate the transition from xml file with TransitionInflator, but again the transitions has to be from support library or made by yourself.
        val sharedElementTransition = TransitionSet()
        val changeBounds = ChangeBounds()
        changeBounds.setPathMotion(ArcMotion())
        sharedElementTransition
                .addTransition(changeBounds)
                .addTransition(ChangeTransform())
                .addTransition(ChangeClipBounds())
                .addTransition(ChangeImageTransform())
        secondFragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = sharedElementTransition
        secondFragment.sharedElementReturnTransition = sharedElementTransition

        // A simple fade animation for the rest of the views (always on the second fragment)
        val mainTransition =  Fade()
        secondFragment.enterTransition = mainTransition
        secondFragment.exitTransition = mainTransition

        // Do the replacement
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addSharedElement(view, "${SecondFragment.SHARED_TRANSITION_NAME}-$itemId") // Add the share element with the transition ID
                .replace(R.id.container, secondFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
    }
}
```

Your FirstFragment.kt:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = FirstFragment()
    }

    // A listener so we can comunicate with MainActivity
    private lateinit var listener: OnItemSelectedListener

    interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        fun onAdSelected(adId: Long, view: View)
    }

    // We use the MainActivity as listener. If activity do not implement the listener interface (OnItemSelectedListener), an error is going to be thrown
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        try {
            listener = activity as OnItemSelectedListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException("${activity!!.javaClass} must implement OnItemSelectedListener")
        }
    }

   ... onCreate, onCreateView, etc...

   inner class ItemAdapter(var items: List<Item> = emptyList()) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

        ...

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            when (holder) {
                is ItemViewHolder -> holder.bind(items[position].id)
            }
        }

        internal inner class AdViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            fun bind(itemId: Long) {

                // Set the onClickListener to call the listener method that should be implemented by MainActivity
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    listener.onItemSelected(itemId, itemView.mySharedTextView)
                }

                // Give the shared element in this first fragment the same transition ID it will have on the second. They need to be unique, so we are appending the item ID to it. They also HAS to be set on the bind instead of onCrateViewHolder, otherwise when your RecyclerView is using a recycled view it will have the wrong item ID on the transition name.
                ViewCompat.setTransitionName(itemView.mySharedTextView, "${SecondFragment.SHARED_TRANSITION_NAME}-$itemId")
            }
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

Your SecondFragment.kt:

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        const val ARG_ITEM_ID = "ARG_ITEM_ID"

        const val SHARED_TRANSITION_NAME = "text_view_transition_name"

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(itemId: Long): SecondFragment {
            val fragment = SecondFragment()
            fragment.arguments = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments!!.putLong(ARG_ITEM_ID, itemID)
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false)

        // Give the shared view on the second/detail fragment the same transition ID from the first
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.mySharedTextView, "$SHARED_TRANSITION_NAME-${arguments!!.getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID)}")

    }

}
```

That's should be all.